# Chrome extension and Django: Verify whether third party cookies are allowed

Tags: javascript, django, cookies, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am using Django's authentication with cookies.

I have a Chrome extension. When the user clicks the extension button the extension sends an xmlHttp request to my_site.com/cookie_test/

The view attached to this url lets the user know whether or not he is logged into my_site.com. (It does other stuff as well.)

**Content_script.js**

```
function got_response(){ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);  
    }
 }

var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "my_site.com/cookie_test/",true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = got_response;
xmlHttp.send();
```

**View function called by my_site.com/cookie_test/**

```
@csrf_exempt
def cookie_test(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse("not logged in")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("logged in")
```

**Case 1: User is logged into my_site and browser allows third-party cookies**

result: "logged in" CORRECT

**Case 2: User is NOT logged in**

result: "not logged in" CORRECT

**Case 3: User IS logged in, but browser does NOT allow third-party cookies**

result: "not logged in" NOT CORRECT

**My question**

If the user's browser does not allow third party cookies, how do I display a message "Change your cookie settings!" In other words, how can I tell the difference between not being logged in and not allowing third party cookies? This can be either server-side or client-side.

Comment: Maybe try using another cookie for the test - set in on every page and check it in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

**Summary:** Do request.session.set_test_cookie() in first call if there are no cookies. In this case respond with "potential cookie issue". In content_script, if get this response, make second call and test for presence of cookie with request.session.test_cookie_worked().

**View function called by first call**

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    if len(request.COOKIES) == 0: 
        # User does not allow third party cookies or cookies are deleted/expired
        request.session.set_test_cookie() # Django function
        return HttpResponse("potential cookie issue")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("not logged in") 
else:
    return HttpResponse("logged in") 
    # would actually continue and do stuff here instead
```

**View function called by second call**

```
if not request.session.test_cookie_worked(): # Django function
    return HttpResponse("third party cookies not allowed")      
else:
    return HttpResponse("not logged in")
```

**content_script.js**

```
function got_response(){ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        if (response_data == "potential cookie issue"){ 
                function got_response2(){ 
                   if (xmlHttp2.readyState == 4){
                        display_response(xmlHttp2.responseText); 
                       /*either not logged in or cookie issue depending on response*/
                    }
                }  
                var xmlHttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp2.open("GET", domain+"/second_call/",true);
                xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = got_response2;
                xmlHttp2.send();
       }
       else{/* not logged in or logged in depending on response*/}
    }
 }

var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "my_site.com/first_call/",true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = got_response;
xmlHttp.send();
```